# How to upgrade Spring boot framework version from 2.0.5 to 2.7.8

Tags: spring-boot

Below is my pom.xml file, I want to upgrade the spring boot version to 2.7.8, kindly share me a blog or any help appreciated. Also when I try updating spring boot version, it gave me spring cloud dependencies, autoconfiguration error.

I tried updating pom.xml directly but it throws auto configuration error.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sboxnw.deploymentpartner</groupId>
    <artifactId>deploymentpartner</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Deployment Partner Service</name>
    <description>Deployment Partner project for managing the deployment partners and there touchpoints</description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>localhost-repo</id>
            <name>Artifactory Server</name>
            <url>http://artifactory01.sboxdc.com/artifactory/caa-library</url>
            <!--<url>http://art01.sboxdc.com/artifactory/caa-library</url> -->
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <project.customname>dponboarding</project.customname>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springfox-version>2.9.2</springfox-version>

        <!-- SonarQuebe Integration Start -->
        <sonar.login>c209c15f97160045279effbba185039c78624299</sonar.login>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.projectKey>dponboardingapi</sonar.projectKey>
        <sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.binaries>target/classes</sonar.binaries>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        <!-- Exclusion(has no business logics) -->
        <sonar.exclusions>
            file:**/target/**,
            file:**/target/generated-sources/**,
            file:**/target/generated-test-sources/**,
            file:**/target/test-classes/**,
            file:**/com/sboxnw/deploymentpartner/domain/*.java,
            file:**/com/sboxnw/deploymentpartner/config/*.java,
            file:**/*Config.java,
            file:**/*Application.java
        </sonar.exclusions>
        <sonar.host.url>
            http://sonarqube.sboxdc.com/sonar
        </sonar.host.url>
        <!-- SonarQuebe Integration Finished -->


        <!-- The main class to start by executing "java -jar" -->
        <start-class>com.sboxnw.deploymentpartner.Application</start-class>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Elastic APM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.apm</groupId>
            <artifactId>apm-agent-attach</artifactId>
            <version>1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Feign Dependency start -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Feign Dependency end -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20170516</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logbook dependency Starts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>logbook-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>logbook-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>logbook-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>logbook-okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logbook dependency Done -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
            <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.73.1</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SugarBox Networks Authorization Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sboxnw.sboxauthlib</groupId>
            <artifactId>sboxauthlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.customname}_${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Jacoco Plugin Started -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <show>public</show>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: provide the error message

Comment: @kerbermeister Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded 
  datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class. Also some cloud dependency error.

Comment: For information on Spring Cloud and Spring Boot compatibility, see https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud. When using Spring Boot 2.7, you'll need Spring Cloud `2021.0.x` (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2021.0-Release-Notes), which means Spring Cloud Config `3.1.x` (`3.1.5` is the latest at this time).